# Xamarin, UWP and a dependence

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uwp

I thought my problem was very simple to resolve but it isn't. I'm creating some new components for `Xamarin`. I have a main `Xamarin` project where I'm testing my components.

My components are a main portable project and for each platform there is specific implementation.

The implementation for `UWP` generates a compatibility error

> Project PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP is not compatible
>   with uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0). Project
>   PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP supports: uap10.0.10240
>   (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) One or more projects are incompatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0. Project PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP is
>   not compatible with uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0) / win10-arm. Project
>   PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP supports: uap10.0.10240
>   (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) One or more projects are incompatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm). Project
>   PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP is not compatible with
>   uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0) / win10-arm-aot. Project
>   PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP supports: uap10.0.10240
>   (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) One or more projects are incompatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot). Project
>   PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP is not compatible with
>   uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0) / win10-x64. Project
>   PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP supports: uap10.0.10240
>   (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) One or more projects are incompatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64). Project
>   PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP is not compatible with
>   uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0) / win10-x64-aot. Project
>   PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP supports: uap10.0.10240
>   (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) One or more projects are incompatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot). Project
>   PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP is not compatible with
>   uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0) / win10-x86. Project
>   PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP supports: uap10.0.10240
>   (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) One or more projects are incompatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86). Project
>   PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP is not compatible with
>   uap10.0 (UAP,Version=v10.0) / win10-x86-aot. Project
>   PSC.Xam.Controls.BindableRadioButton.UWP supports: uap10.0.10240
>   (UAP,Version=v10.0.10240) One or more projects are incompatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot). NuGet package restore failed.

I checked the configuration of UWP main project and the implementation project and both are the same settings.

[image: UWP Settings]

[image: UWP Implementation Settings]

In the implementation project, I have a reference to the portable project and its settings are:

[image: Portable project settings]

If I deploy the project and run it, it seems working fine on my desktop.

Also, I receive two other errors:

> Duplicate Entry
>
> 0xdef00532 - Conflicting values for resource 'Files/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/TabbedPageStyle.xbf' GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE

I checked my `Package.appxmanifest` and `Dependencies` is as requested.

```
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" 
                        MinVersion="10.0.0.0" 
                        MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
```

Comment: I could not get your solution structure from your screenshot. Could you share a sample project to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I've publish my project on GitHub https://github.com/erossini/BindableRadioButtonCheckboxList

Comment: Also, I tried to remove `Xamarin Forms` and reinstall it but I can't.

Comment: Any updates for this kind of error?

Comment: I am also seeing this error and would like a solution

Answer (score 1):

In order to use .NET Standard 2.0 in UWP, you need to target Fall Creators Update (FCU) as the minimum version of your UWP project. That’s because .NET Standard 2.0 contains many APIs that require FCU to make them work in the context of the UWP execution environment, specifically AppContainer.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/25/uwp-net-standard-2-0-preview/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/10/announcing-uwp-support-for-net-standard-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

Find project.json file and replace "uap10.0" with "uap10.0.10586"

Comment: I don't have a `project.json` file